# how to use touch events on uicollectionviewcontroller

Tags: ios

In my app I have an `uicollectionviewcontroller` which has cell, right now I'm able to move my cells and switch theirs place but I want to know is that possible that use touch events instead move in this viwcontroller?

What I want is that put my cell ON each other by using touch.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried ??

Here is something to get you on your way,

Put this in the method for the Gest. Recog

```
CGPoint hitPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.collectionView];
NSIndexPath *hitIndex = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:hitPoint];
```

From the hitIndex, you have your cell to do as you please.